# Why spring boot scanBasePackages conflict with spring.jackson.date-format

Tags: json, spring, application.properties

I config the json date format in application.properties with annotation

```
//in application.properties
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = (arrayOf("com.khidi")))
```

the json date format not working,but I remove scanBasePages, it's working.
I need set the scanBasePages, because some bean in another package, how to fix it. thx.

Comment: Show the code where you setup object mapper. I think you have such. Or many some other custom configuration is ruining it for you

Comment: I found that a piece of code conflict the config

 @Configuration
 class CustomRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration : RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration() {

 ｝

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a piece of code conflict the config

```
@Configuration
class CustomRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration : RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration() {

｝
```